# Creating a Java API for Parsing a CSV

Tags: java, json, api

I need to create a java API that takes in a CSV file and returns a JSON with some parsed data from the CSV. I've currently built a Java program in Eclipse with a bunch of static class methods that if passed in the file name of the CSV as a command-line argument to the main function, will do the parsing and create the JSON.

How do I go about modifying this code so that it will function as an API? In specific, the API should be able to accept a .csv file in the following way.

```
POST http://<YOUR HOST HERE>/scrub/:csv_file
```

Then, how do I go about returning the JSON?   Thank you in advance for the help -- first time writing an API as opposed to a standard Java program.

Comment: An API is an jar file containg your CsvParser propably with public parse( method. Why do you need POST? Or do you want to create a Web Service?